# Load data from the model into form fields through AJAX in Symfony2. Right way

Tags: ajax, api, symfony

In my application I use two entities.

```
1) City
2) Shop
```

They have a relationship **one-to-many**

For example:

```
- Barcelona:city
-- Decathlon:shop
-- Salewa:shop

- New York:city
-- Puma:shop
-- Nike:shop
```

**First step:**

Via the dropdown list the user selects a city:

[image: select box]

It raises the event by changing the value of the list. At this point the javascript code must request and obtain all the stores for the selected city.

**Second step:**

Show the second drop-down list with the values of stores for the selected city.

[image]

Ok. Now my questions:

1) **How to make a request to the data model?** (I am interested not so much JS code but backend architecture. Should I do API or rather request data from the controller to the same page?)

2) How should look the part of code implements the class of this form?

Answer (score 1):

1) **Request.** The best way is a JSON response via a separate controller. Everything is very simple here.

2) **Form.** This question is more interesting. The City dropdown should be a **not-mapped** field of City Entity. The Shop field should be a simple Shop entity field with no choices if you don't have default city in your form (`'choices' => array()` in field options), or make it select all default city shops by the `query_builder` option. When you get a response from the backend after selecting a city, just append all possible options to the shop dropdown which consist a shop ID as their value.

Answer (score 0):

There are many schools of thought about implementing this but I am personally a big fan of sending the whole relation to the view and managing the switching with javascript, so something like this would do:

```
return $this->render('YourBundle:Controller:index.html.twig', array(
        'cities' => $cities_with_shops_json,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
```

The javascript part is just capturing the event but there are many examples in google. 
http://javascript.about.com/library/bldydrop1.htm

One advantage of this is avoiding the ajax call every time the user click on the select.

Comment: Heard anything about the caching?

Comment: Caching is ok for your server performance, think networkwise, maybe you have clients using wireless, anyway whatever floats your boat if network performance is not an issue, and you are willing to do it the ajax way, then a controller returning json would be fine.